# Retrain random forest with important variables

Tags: r, machine-learning, random-forest, importance

So I have a classification problem with around 2000 predictors. First I run a random forest model to get important variables. Then I only use those variables (let say the top 30) to run the model again. I got a substantial improvement in cross-validation accuracy and AUC. I am just wondering whether it is a good practice and there is any theoretical background behind this?

Comment: My main concern would be overfitting. Since what happens when you're fitting the second RF depends on the steps and decisions you made for the first RF, you've starting to wander in the Garden of Forking Paths.

Comment: With regard to @Sycorax's comment, you should cross-validate the whole procedure, repeating the selection of the top thirty in each fold.

Answer (score 1):

You can consider this a regularization technique and in general it is a great idea to reduce your feature space to reduce overfitting. Moreover, since you are using random forests it increases the chances that each individual tree will get some important feature instead of "garbage" one which can be important if you don't construct a large number of trees. This is, however, a balancing act and you might want to experiment with number of top features you keep.