# Using machine learning model for predictions

Tags: machine-learning, predictive-models, random-forest

I am trying to use my random forest model for predictions. I only want to select important variables(ex:top 50), and use the saved RF model to predict the response variable, changing the predictor values.

Do I have to re-train the RF model for top 50 variables and use that model to perform predictions?

My understanding is since the original RF model has more variables than 50, I cannot use the original model for predictions.

Comment: Yes you will have to retrain your model. You are trying to assign weights to different predictors through training. By selecting the top 50, you have arbitrarily assigned a weight of zero to all other predictors.

Is there a reason you are doing this? And how are you estimating what an important variable is?

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't make a lot of sense to only supply the top 50 most important predictors to the RF for prediction. You will need to specify some values for the other predictors, anyway, what will you use? Either [retrain the model based on your selected predictors](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/358739/1352), or simply use the full RF.

Comment: Thanks Stephan. 
What if I only want to use top 50 variables not all the variables given by RF model, then how can I use the model to do the predictions? I do have to re-train with top 50 prior making predictions, right?

Comment: As Stephan writes in his last sentence, either retrain the model based on your selected (top 50) predictors, or simply use the full RF.  If you are ruling out the latter, that leaves you with the former.